# Limit memory used for mongoDb

Tags: linux, mongodb

Is there any way to limit using RAM for mongodb on Debian? I'm looking for a solution fo about 8 hours, but have no results.

Comment: You could use ulimit but it could effect performance if your working set exceeds the amount you allocate

Answer (score 3):

I have heard that some folks have had success using [lxc](http://lxc.sourceforge.net/) to isolate MongoDB on Linux. There are other container technologies out there, but that seems to be the most mainstream option.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using cgroups.

Some tutorials are available as well as shell script for Ubuntu 14.04.

See also [Is there any option to limit mongodb memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6861184) on Stack Overflow.